.NET Sending SMTP emails with MailKit fails while limilabs works
I have a .NET application running on a Cloud Run instance using VPC and I've been trying to implement a way of sending emails using a google SMTP server.
My public IP is whitelisted on the relay side. The relay is working fine when I test it with telnet.
However, trying to send email with MailKit as well as the .NET mail framework is failing.
My MailKit implementation is a following:
 using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {
                await client.ConnectAsync("my-host.gmail.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls).ConfigureAwait(false);
                await client.SendAsync(emailMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
                await client.DisconnectAsync(true).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

For the above I've tried with client.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls13; as well as port 456 and all Tls options available.
The error is consistently:
An exception occurred while sending the email: MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpProtocolException: The SMTP server has unexpectedly disconnected. 2024-04-12 18:09:29.676 CEST at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpStream.ReadAhead(CancellationToken cancellationToken) 2024-04-12 18:09:29.676 CEST at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpStream.ReadResponse(CancellationToken cancellationToken) 2024-04-12 18:09:29.676 CEST at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpStream.SendCommand(String command, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 2024-04-12 18:09:29.676 CEST at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.SendEhlo(Boolean connecting, String helo, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 2024-04-12 18:09:29.676 CEST at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.Ehlo(Boolean connecting, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 2024-04-12 18:09:29.676 CEST at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.PostConnect(Stream stream, String host, Int32 port, SecureSocketOptions options, Boolean starttls, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 2024-04-12 18:09:29.676 CEST at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.Connect(String host, Int32 port, SecureSocketOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
With the .NET Mail library I tried various combinations of settings and ports 587, 25 and 465 such as:
           System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            var client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("my-host.gmail.com", 587)
            {
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                TargetName = "my-host.gmail.com",
            };

            var mailMessage = new MailMessage
            {
                From = new MailAddress("my-email@email.com"),
                To = { new MailAddress("to-email@email.com","email") },
                Body = message,
                Subject = subject,
                IsBodyHtml = true
            };


With the response:
An exception occurred while sending the email: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: 4.7.0 Try again later, closing connection. (EHLO) 2024-04-12 15:56:50.993 CEST at System.Net.Mail.EHelloCommand.CheckResponse(LineInfo[] lines)
However, Limilabs.Mail did go through but it is not the solution I want to go forward with since it needs a licence.
Limilab config:
            using (Smtp smtp = new Smtp())
            {
                smtp.Connect("my-host.gmail.com");
 
                smtp.StartTLS();
                
                MailBuilder builder = new MailBuilder();
                builder.Text = "text";
                builder.From.Add(new MailBox("my-email@email.com"));
                builder.To.Add(new MailBox("sender-email@email.com"));
 
                IMail email = builder.Create();
 
                smtp.SendMessage(email);
 
                smtp.Close();
            }


I am trying to understand what Limilab does differently and what am I missing.
I have to mention I have no control over the mail server so I cannot look into its setting or try to debug the issue on that side on any way. I know it requires no auth since it relies on IP and for whitelisted IPs the relay does not require TLS - but it is encouraged.

According to both Exception StackTraces, both MailKit and Limilabs failed in the EHLO command which is the first command sent to the server. The server responded in the Limilabs case that the server was temporarily unavailable (hence the "4.7.0 Try again later, closing connection." text). MailKit likely got the same error (I just released v4.5.0 that will include this info in the exception message). I don't see how Limilabs could have successfully sent the message unless you got lucky by trying a second time when the server was accepting connections.
If you try again with MailKit, it would probably work just like it did with Limilabs.

After more debugging I realized that the issue was due to the fact that MailKit was using localhost for ehlo command. I am guessing that is because of the way Cloud Run instances are running.
Setting LocalDomain = the whitelisted IP of my Cloud Nat property before the ConnectAsync command fixed my issue.
